# Issues with reading .bed files and compressing output in a specific format

Tags: python, gzip, bioinformatics

```
import os #handles the gzipped output like the example file
file_name = "exampleziptotxt.bed"
out_file_root = "example_by_chrom"
file_handle_dict = {}

file_reader=open(file_name)

for line in file_reader:
    ff=line.strip().split(",")
    chrom_name=ff[0]
    if not (chrom_name in file_handle_dict):
        out_file_chrom_name=out_file_root+"."+chrom_name+".bed"
        out_file_chrom_name_handle=open(out_file_chrom_name,"w")
        file_handle_dict[chrom_name]=out_file_chrom_name_handle
    # write the line in the appropriate output file
    file_handle_dict[chrom_name].write(line)
    # file_handle_dict[chrom_name].write("%s\n"%"\t".join(ff))

file_reader.close()

# now close all open files
for chrom_name in file_handle_dict:
    file_handle_dict[chrom_name].close()
```

I would like to rewrite the above code so that the output is multiple gzipped files using gzip or alternative. I am unsure how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Each file corresponds to a chromosome and contained within each file is "all" the gene names, positions, and strandedness. The idea is to take those .bed files and compress them

Comment: Please don't change the question after it received an answer. I rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few small changes are needed, `import gzip` (don't need `os`), add `.gz` to the name, use `gzip.open` instead of `open` for the write, and use `.encode()` on the line to make it into bytes.

```
import gzip

file_name = "exampleziptotxt.bed"
out_file_root = "example_by_chrom"
file_handle_dict = {}

file_reader=open(file_name)

for line in file_reader:
    ff=line.strip().split(",")
    chrom_name=ff[0]
    if not (chrom_name in file_handle_dict):
        out_file_chrom_name=out_file_root+"."+chrom_name+".bed.gz"
        out_file_chrom_name_handle=gzip.open(out_file_chrom_name,"w")
        file_handle_dict[chrom_name]=out_file_chrom_name_handle
    # write the line in the appropriate output file
    file_handle_dict[chrom_name].write(line.encode())
    # file_handle_dict[chrom_name].write("%s\n"%"\t".join(ff))

file_reader.close()

# now close all open files
for chrom_name in file_handle_dict:
    file_handle_dict[chrom_name].close()
```

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You copied my answer into the question and then asked a different question? The whole point of stackoverflow is to maintain a record of questions and answers. Not to overwrite and destroy them. And then you ask the exact same question as a different user? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63948681/1180620

Comment: @MarkAdler I rolled back the question.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to all of this. My intent was to get clarification as to how to modify input. And I was locked out, I was'nt trying to screw you over